# why JPA - foreign key doesn't make error "ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: jpa

> quote **When using JPA, a problem occurs that is stored without the correct foreign key.**
>   quote ( spring - JPA 사용시  올바른 foreign key 없이도 저장이 되는 문제가 발생 )

The relationship(join) was created through JPA.
prodDetail.prodNo has Prod.no as foreign key.

*// hibernate

  alter table prod_detail
    add constraint FKemc8ttnx3c8rl0d3u9s7xr964
    foreign key (no)
    references prod (no)*

I thought that ProdDetail object with a foreign key-col without a stored Prod.no would not be saved (= insert), but it is saved.
You can do the opposite. Why?

so I try this on mysql workbanch.

*ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails* 
ERROR occur

**Why is there no error in JPA?**

here is my codes

please help me. 
(if you are korean? please, speak to me in KOR )
thanks~

```
@Entity
public class Prod {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "no")
    private Long no;
    private String name;
    private String thumbnailUrl;
    private Long originPrice;
    private Long discPrice;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    @Transient
    private boolean inBasket;
}
-----------------------------------------------------
@Entity
public class ProdDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String content;
    private String imageUrl;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @PrePersist
    public void createdAt() {
        this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="prod_no" )
    private Prod prod;

-----------------------------------------------------


    // jUnit test
    @Test
        public void insertTodetailTest() {
            ProdDetail pd = new ProdDetail();
            pd.setContent("test product 1");
            pd.setImageUrl("test Product url");
            detailRepo.save(pd);
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would it fail? The constraint says: 'the column `prod_detail` must correspond to some value in the `prod (no)` column'. It does **not** say '`prod_detail` must be provided', though.

Add a `NOT NULL` constraint to `prod_detail` (`@JoinColumn(nullable = false)`) as well as a runtime check `@ManyToOne(optional = false)` and the problem should go away.